# Disable redirect in fb:request-form Send/Cancel button

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, xfbml, fbrequest-form

How do I disable the redirect in Facebook's invite form?

```
<fb:serverfbml style="width: 600px; height: 650px;">
        <script type="text/fbml">
            <fb:request-form 
                action="index.php"
                method="POST"
                invite="true"
                type="MyApp"
                content="Please have a look. 
        <fb:req-choice url='http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/' label='View Now!' />">                 
    <div class="clearfix" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
        <fb:multi-friend-selector condensed="true" style="width: 600px;" />
    </div>
    <fb:request-form-submit />
</fb:request-form>
```

After selecting friends, you will see the final Send Invite dialog with your template. After you click send or cancel, how do i disable the redirect by just closing the the dialog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just blank out or remove the action parameter of the form?

Comment: nope, that will just redirect to your provide inside the iframe that was housing the form. :(

Answer (score 0):

I can't get this work too, but someone in the facebook developer forum seems solved it:

```
<script>
function callback()
{
// do whatever
}
</script>

<fb:request-form action="javascript:callback()" >
</fb:request-form>
```

http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=213360

(this does not work for me....)

Answer (score 0):

just add `target="_blank"` in the  request-form parameters...

Answer (score 0):

[FBML has since been deprecated.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/)

Here is an easy alternative to the `<fb:multi-friend-selector>` :

You can use the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) to call the [`FB.ui()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) method with the `apprequests` parameter.  This will display to your users a popup similar in UI to the `<fb:multi-friend-selector>`.  Here is an example of what it looks like :

[image]

And this is what the code to call the `FB.ui()` method looks like :

```
  FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'My Great Request',
    }, function(){
      // handle response data here
   });
  }
```

The response that you get from `apprequests` is this :

- **The Request Object ID** : To get the full Request ID, concatenate this with a user ID from the to field: `<request_object_id>_<user_id>`
- **to** : An array of the recipient user IDs for the request that was created.